# How are the Witches playing 'the Shakespeare way'?

Tags: the-witches

In the 2020 remake of *The Witches*, when the Grand High Witch gives Charlie the Number 86 Delayed Action Mouse Maker potion, Charlie refuses to open his mouth and the Grand High Witch says

> Open his trap.
>
> Open it.
>
> [croakily] Okay.
>
> That’s how you wanna play, we’ll play the Shakespeare way.

The Witches the proceed to pour the potion into Charlie's ear.

What specifically is 'the Shakespeare way'? I assume it's a reference to *Macbeth* and its witches, but I'm unsure how.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's presumably a reference to Hamlet, not Macbeth. Hamlet's father was [killed by Claudius pouring poison in his ear](https://shakespeare.mit.edu/hamlet/full.html#:%7E:text=Upon%20my%20secure%20hour%20thy%20uncle%20stole%2C%0AWith%20juice%20of%20cursed%20hebenon%20in%20a%20vial%2C%0AAnd%20in%20the%20porches%20of%20my%20ears%20did%20pour%0AThe%20leperous%20distilment%3B%20whose%20effect%0AHolds%20such%20an%20enmity%20with%20blood%20of%20man).

> *Upon my secure hour thy uncle stole,
>
> **With juice of cursed hebenon in a vial,
>
> And in the porches of my ears did pour
>
> The leperous distilment;** whose effect
>
> Holds such an enmity with blood of man*

Comment: In [Machbeth](https://www.folger.edu/explore/shakespeares-works/macbeth/read/#:~:text=Than%C2%A0wishest%C2%A0should%C2%A0be%C2%A0undone.%C2%A0Hie%C2%A0thee%C2%A0hither%2C%0A%C2%A0That%C2%A0I%C2%A0may%C2%A0pour%C2%A0my%C2%A0spirits%C2%A0in%C2%A0thine%C2%A0ear), 'spirits' are administered by ear, but those spirits are ill feeling rather than literal poison. *Than wishest should be undone. Hie thee hither, That I may pour my spirits in thine ear*.

Comment: @Valorum I feel as if this is more famous in Hamlet -- I mean, The Simpsons Hamlet shows Moe pouring a drop of poison in Homer's ear.

Comment: @OwenReynolds - Indeedly. "Poison being administered by ear" is so synonymous with Hamlet that I can't think of any other major work where it happens, other than where they're parodying or referencing Hamlet.

Comment: @Valorum Interesting. I've [posted a question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/25980/17) about the history of that trope, to see if *Hamlet* was the true origin or just the [Trope Codifier](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TropeCodifier).

Comment: @Randal'Thor - If memory serves, the story is a retelling of an older monomyth. Shakespeare rarely invented plots.

Comment: @Valorum *Hamlet* is one of the plays that doesn't have a clearly identifiable precursor, although the good folks of Lit.SE have [done](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16889/17) a lot of [research](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/17735/17) about the hypothesised *Ur-Hamlet* that was Shakespeare's source.